# Caret library fails to load

Tags: r, r-caret

I successfully installed caret but when loading the library I get the following error message:

> library(caret)
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘caret’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
> namespace ‘generics’ 0.0.2 is already loaded, but >= 0.1.0 is required

what does 0.1.0 refer to?

Comment: update generics to at least version  0.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, apparently some required dependencies for the caret package need to be updated. However installing it with DEPENDENCIES = TRUE, did not fix the problem for me.

**What did work was:**

Close all your .rmd files in RStudio and then click on the 'update' button in the tab with the packages:
[image]

This should update all your packages including the ones caret needs be updated, to work with their latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by uninstalling the caret package, restarting R and installing the package from zip file.

Answer (score 0):

It is asking about the latest version of generics package. It could be solved either by manually installing some earlier version of package caret or updating the base r packages.
`update.packages()`
If it asks for permission then use sudo

Answer (score -1):

First use this:

install.packages('hardhat')
library(hardhat)
install.packages('ipred')
library(ipred)

then,you can use library(caret).

Comment: Can you provide some more explanation on what does your code do?